# Django Model - Dynamic case-insensitive match query

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

Very simple.
I need a IN with CaseInsensitive and Full Like.

**Example**

Search Probe: "Crit,Norm"

I need to find all of this rows with column's value: "critical, Crit, crit, normal, Normal"

**PostgreSql**

Searching on google, I found Postgres function "similar to"

`lower(column_name) similar to '%(crit|norm)%';`

Is there a way to make it in Django?

**Adding New Info after Yugandhar Chaudhari response**

The question was not complete. The search probes are inside an array.
I would like something like this:

`probes = ["Crit","Norm"]
model_name.objects.filter(columnname_icontains_in = probes)`

Answer (score 0):

For case insensitive match you can try

`from django.db.models import Q
 YouModel.objects.filter(Q(column_name__iexact="crit")|Q(column_name__iexact="norm"))`

If you want to find a substring pattern

`from django.db.models import Q
 YouModel.objects.filter(Q(column_name__icontains="crit")|Q(column_name__icontains="norm"))`

**After update**:

```
values = ['crit', 'norm']
qobjs = Q() #empty objects
for value in values:
    qobjs |= Q(coulmn_name__icontains=value) #Dynamically add Q objects 
result = YourModel.objects.filter(qobjs)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I put some more info in the question

Comment: so what if you do `model_name.objects.filter(columnname__icontains_in = probes)` please note __

Comment: Unsupported lookup 'icontains' for TextField or join on the field not permitted.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. You solution is the the code im actually use. I was hoping in a way to avoid iteration

Comment: you are welcome but in this solution query is executed only once not each time in iteration and I dont think looping would be overhead on a simple list here.. keep me updated if you find one..cheers